# send data over the internet on a safe way

Tags: c#, sockets

I am building a program for myself that will save my passwords. Now I have the following questions. Because I have a lot of computers (one for work, three for myself), I want to keep the passwords in sync with a server. But now my question is **what is the safest way to send data over the internet with c#? Is it possible to make the connection so safe that I can send passwords over it?** And maybe any suggestions for the app.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Have you heard of WCF?

Comment: Thx for the title and I am looking into the WCF part :)

Comment: I'd recommend looking at KeePass 2 as a starting point. The database file is encrypted and is shared between devices by an (arbitrary) cloud solution. Pro: You son't need your own server program.

Comment: @DasKrümelmonster So it is safe to put a keepass2 database on dropbox?

Comment: From the docs: Yes, that is secure. As the database file is encrypted using strong encryption algorithms, you could give your database file to anyone. Just remember to use a strong password and/or a key file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can make it reasonably secure. First, I would recommend **against** writing your own protocol stack, simply because it is so incredibly easy to make a simple mistake that would make it trivial to hack the security.

( Obviously there are plenty of already existing services (like 1password, passpack, etc) but I assume you know that already. )

I would recommend that you focus on the syncing and UI and **leave the security to alredy proven libraries**. One such solution is to use SSH with RSA authentication and known host keys. This is in use on many production sites and AFAIK considered reasonably secure (though there was one [hole](http://www.openssh.com/security.html) in one of the most popular implementations, OpenSSH, some years ago that was pretty bad). The SSH protocol can be used as a carrier for all kinds of different protocol, including your own password-syncing protocol (for that you could just use SOAP or JSON-RPC or something similar that there are plenty of libraries for).

You can then integrate directly with C# by using a SSH client library (https://sshnet.codeplex.com was the first Google hit). I have no experience using C# directly to talk SSH, though. What I usually do is to let an existing SSH client (PuTTY, for example) open up a port forward and then use regular TCP sockets. It all depends on how slick you want the sync app, but since you are writing it for yourself only, I would go with the latter.

If you are clever writing your app, you don't need a server part except of your own (for example, SSH implements SFTP for file storage).

A similar idea is to use SSL. If you pre-trust the certificate chain, this can be made secure enough but my experience is that the default SSL socket API in C# is way too much tied into the Windows architecture, making things like custom certificate validation trickier. Using a publicly exposed server to your service (directly of via IIS) also opens up a lot of new attack vectors.

Comment: Heartbleed is a hole in OpenSSL, not OpenSSH. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55300/do-i-need-to-worry-about-my-ssh-keys-if-my-system-was-vulnerable-to-heartbleed

Comment: Phew .. damn abbreviations .. sry.